# How do you add a parent navigation item to quick launch with no link actually pointing to it?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I am currently using SharePoint 2013 Online and am using a managed navigation structure to support 3 levels on the quick list. So for example:

```
 Item 1 (Parent)
 --Nested Item 1 (Child)
 ---Nested Item 1A
```

What I am trying to do is just have the parent items in the navigation list just display the children elements and not act like a link to a page. So in other words if I was to click on "Item 1" the child element "Nested Item 1" would display in a box underneath it and I would not be redirected to another page. I have no idea how to do this and any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box this is not possible.

Workaround -

1. Take a look at jQuery Accordion widget
2. Now after page load convert the left navigation into an accordion. For that you should convert the left navigation elements into accordion elements using jQuery. And then invoke the jQuery Accordion.